# UITableView "bulk select" not showing selected checkmarks in the selection circles, showing right side checkmark not left side

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am attempting to reproduce this behavior (see screenshot below, the "mail multiple select to delete" behavior) on an iOS8 Swift application. **When set to "edit" the left selection circles are presented, but upon selection they do not change to a blue checkmark.** (Nothing visible happens, or it happens off to the right ... off screen.)

From various Google searches I've tried setting the accessoryType to be checkbox, but that appears on the right (not the left.) [Is that old advice, is adding a checkmark still the approach to take?]

I've scoured this sample (even downloading it and running it and tweaking it closer to my code, and it works) but I cannot see the delta between it and my application.

Some data points:

- Xcode 7
- iOS8 + (testing on 8 and 9)
- Swift 2.0
- Storyboard configuration of the tableview, etc.
- Custom layout cells. They use the content view for some text, nothing outside. Autolayout.
- Single selection when NOT editing (or so I believe)
- Multiple selection when editing (to get this effect.)
- DataSource returns canEdit "true" for most (not all) cells. Circles only show next to those editable, matching expectations.
- Delegate is not returning any "editing style" value. (Tried w/ & w/o.)
- Delegate does NOT deselect in "didSelect" handler.
- When I try setting accesoryType to Checkmark in didSelect (which many posting suggest, but I don't see it in the sample) it comes on the right not left.

Other StackOverflow questions / answers imply something is causing UITableView to fail to know to put the checkmark on the left not the right. I can believe that, but I cannot find it. Any help appreciated.

**The desired effect (from sample screenshot):**

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableMultiSelect/Introduction/Intro.html

[image: The blue checkbox selection from sample]

**Table Settings**

[image: Table Settings from Storyboard]

**Table Cell Settings**

[image: Table Cell Settings from Storyboard]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you have `selectionStyle = .None` in your cellForRowAtIndexPath, remove it.

I was in the same exact boat as you (using Xcode 7, iOS9, Swift 2.0). Most of the articles I found online were about the checkmark on the right and my storyboard looked perfect. My only problem is that I could never get the checkmark on the left to show up when I tapped on the row.

With your post I was able to compare source code and figure it out - thanks!

Comment: Good catch. I found exactly this over the weekend, it was some stray code from a previous iteration, and removing it (allowing selections to display) fixed the problem. (For me it was in my cell sub-class.) I was preparing to post my own answer, but am happy to accept yours. BTW: I belatedly noticed I was getting no visible selection indication (as well as no checkmark) and realized it was the likely cause. To answer my own (other) question above, there is no need to set a checkmark, the selection state does the job.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure cell's tint color is NOT white, otherwise you will get a white checkmark over a white circle...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a combination of the accepted answer as well as the UITableViewCell Selection set in the storyboard/IB. I had Selection set to "None" to prevent selection highlighting. You can't do that if you want the edit checkmarks to show. Just an additional help for someone who may find this down the road!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. 
Set selectionStyle as Default.

My method in sub-class UITableViewCell.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        //Here I solved problem
        let bgView = UIView()
        bgView.frame = self.frame
        bgView.backgroundColor = selectionColor //Here your color

        self.selectedBackgroundView? = bgView
    }
```